# Creating a mobile site

Tags: android, mobile, web

I currently have a website that is only intended for a computer monitor, however I want to expand to mobile devices however I am a little unsure on how to proceed.

This is how I think I should proceed, correct me if I'm wrong.

I can have an alternative verson of my site say on a sub domain, say "m.website.com" and have that dynamic for mobile screens. Then have some function to detect if its its loading the site on a mobile and redirect if needed.

I could also create a android application by just creating a web view and display the webpage directly from the mobile site.

Is there not other ways, better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe will work, but is a bit out of date.  The current trend is to make your site a "Responsive Design", which is a buzzword to mean that your design changes it's layout to adjust to the size of the users display dynamically.

Well made responsive sites will rearrange columns, drop the number of columns to say go from 3 on a desktop to 1 on a mobile, and simply layouts in general on small screens.

Here are a few good starting places:

- [Responsive Web Design Guidelines and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/)
- [Responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

A friend/coworker of mine made this responsive site open source and it's pretty well recieved, might be a good place to learn some tricks and best practices:

- [responsive-wedding](https://github.com/bmgdev/responsive-wedding)
- [A live demo of it in action](http://sarahlovesbradley.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to creating your mobile website. Either you design a separate mobile website for it then host on m.website.com or you extend your CSS script to handle the website's screen width then on every page of your website, you include a meta tag to help you scale screen widths then determine what CSS to output.

Use the links below to start learning as well as search for more tutorials online.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-a-responsive-website-video-tutorial (Contains video and sample scripts)

http://www.lingulo.com/tutorials/css/how-to-build-a-html5-website-from-scratch